# Read the file in UNIX without Using Unix Command (may be Datastage routine)

Tags: datastage

I have a file in a Unix path which has data like:
 2019-06-21,2019-06-22|2019-06-22,2019-06-23

I want to read this date and pass this to User Variable Activity .

I am not allowed to Use ant Unix command to read the file.

I read some forum and found that it can be done by routine activity,but not sure where to write the routine and whats the routine name.

Can anyone help in this

```
* open FinaltestOut.txt
OPENSEQ /home/shivam : '\' : FinaltestOut.txt TO H.FinaltestOut.txt THEN
CALL DSLogInfo("******************** File " : FinaltestOut.txt : " opened successfully", "JobControl")
END ELSE
CALL DSLogInfo("Unable to open file", "JobControl")
ABORT
END 

READSEQ FinaltestOut.txt.RECORD FROM H.FinaltestOut.txt ELSE
Call DSLogWarn("******************** File is empty", "JobControl")
END

firstline = Trim(FinaltestOut.txt.RECORD[1,32]," ","A") ******* will read the first 32 chars 
Call DSLogInfo("******************** Record read: " : firstline, "JobControl")
CLOSESEQ H.FinaltestOut.txt
```

Comment: Yes I want this.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : You can use execute command activity to cat this File.
Step 2 : Then use User Variable activity to get the execute command output.
Step 3 : Use Field function inside the UV activity to get the desired field.

Note : Here we just use cat command that too in execute command activity. Its the easy approach to resolve your issue.